# Getting Emacs lsp-mode to work with this matlab-langserver

Tags: lsp-mode, matlab, lsp

I am trying to get this [Matlab language server](https://github.com/tokoro10g/matlab-langserver) to work with lsp-mode. Following the instructions in lsp-mode's github page, I inserted the following in my `init.el`:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :config
  (setq lsp-auto-configure t)
  (lsp-register-client
   (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-stdio-connection "~/.local/share/git/matlab-langserver/matlab-langserver.sh")
                    :major-modes '(matlab-mode)
                    :server-id 'matlab-langserver)))
```

Where `matlab-langserver.sh` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd ~/.local/share/git/matlab-langserver/
MATLABROOT="/opt/MATLAB/R2018b"
java -Djava.library.path=$MATLABROOT/bin/glnxa64 -cp $MATLABROOT/extern/engines/java/jar/engine.jar:$MATLABROOT/java/jar/jmi.jar:./build/libs/lsp-matlab-0.1.jar org.tokor.lspmatlab.Application
```

That last java command being the way to start the server. Here's what happens if I just run this script:

```
➜  matlab-langserver git:(master) ✗ ./matlab-langserver.sh
2019-11-27 12:50:27.252 [main] INFO  org.tokor.lspmatlab.Application {} - Starting server
2019-11-27 12:50:27.542 [main] INFO  org.tokor.lspmatlab.MATLABEngineSingleton {} - Could not find existing sessions. Starting MATLAB Engine...
```

When I load up a Matlab m file and start `lsp`, it connects successfully to the server, but then doesn't do anything. No autocomplete, no hover, nothing.

Here is some sample output from `*lsp-log*`

```
[Trace - 12:41:59 PM] Sending request 'textDocument/signatureHelp - (14)'.
Params: {
  "textDocument": {
    "uri": "file:///home/user/Documents/freq_resp_with_damping.m"
  },
  "position": {
    "line": 33,
    "character": 16
  }
}


[Trace - 12:41:59 PM] Received response 'textDocument/signatureHelp - (14)' in 10ms.
Result: null


[Trace - 12:42:07 PM] Sending request 'textDocument/signatureHelp - (15)'.
Params: {
  "textDocument": {
    "uri": "file:///home/user/Documents/freq_resp_with_damping.m"
  },
  "position": {
    "line": 60,
    "character": 27
  }
}


[Trace - 12:42:07 PM] Received response 'textDocument/signatureHelp - (15)' in 10ms.
Result: null
```

Any ideas how I can get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried with the `eglot` package?

Comment: Yes I did. The behavior appears to be the same, although I'm not able to access eglot's I/O log of the conversation with the server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is not in the client (`lsp-mode`) but it is in the server. My guess is that it needs some special `initializationOptions` or it is broken(e. g. does not support the file you are testing with).

The options are:

- Test with other clients that are working fine. I usually check what vscode client does since most of the time there is no documentation on what additionally the server require.
- Ask in the server repo for guidance.